# Which control is the best in the toolbox for me?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, toolbox

[plan for statistic form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd1LM.png)

On the left topside i made a plan on how i want to find a controll which has a range of 100.

Is in microsoft forms there a control that you would recommend for my plan?

I want it near like this [what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLjaL.png)

I think about using a simple scrollbar but it looks ugly.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Not try a progress bar? These have 100 values, but only take integers for input. So, if you want floats, you will either need to create a separate value, and do the assigning to the progress bar with the formula:

fltInitialNumber - (fltInitialNumber % 1)

Or try to find a control that will accept floats and is also based on 100. I glanced through the other options though, and I think this is the best option,

[Assignment of the value to the Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56TGO.png)
[Progress Bar displayed on Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvIgU.png)